# Have written code that shows a directory, how would I make it so that java says whether this outcome is a file, or another directory/folder?

Tags: java, file, methods

so this program currently lists all folders and files in a directory. I want to know if it is possible to add another bit of code that says whether the output is a file or a directory. For example, if it outputted "Test.txt" then it will display something like "Test.txt = a file". 
Thanks.

```
import java.io.File;

public class CS1702_Lab7ex7_5 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String dir_name = "c:\\temp\\"; //Or another directory
    File dir = new File(dir_name);

    File[] dir_list = dir.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<dir_list.length;++i)
    {
        System.out.println(dir_list[i].getName());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two possibilities:

1. Is Directory
2. Is File

You can use an evaluation expression, With one of the two available sentences:

```
import java.io.File;

public class CS1702_Lab7ex7_5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String dir_name = "c:\\tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.72"; // Or another
                                                            // directory
     File dir = new File(dir_name);

    File[] dir_list = dir.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < dir_list.length; ++i) {
        /*
         * dir_list[i].isDirectory(): True, print directory. False, print
         * "File"
         */
        System.out.println(dir_list[i].getName() + (dir_list[i].isDirectory() ? " Directory" : " File"));
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dir_list.isDirectory()` on the items of the returned list of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the [java File API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

[isDirectory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) returns, if the file is a directory or not.

[isFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()) returns, if it is a file.

You could also use a for each loop to iterate over the files:

```
public void listAllFiles(File folder, boolean subfolders) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName() + " (folder)");
            if(subfolders)
                listAllFiles(fileEntry, subfolders);
        } else if(fileEntery.isFile()){
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName() + " (file) ["+getProperties(fileEntry)+"]");
        }
    }
}

public String getProperties(File f) {
    String prop = "";
    prop += f.canRead()?"+r":"";
    prop += f.canWrite()?"+w":"";
    prop += f.canExecute()?"+e":"";
    prop += f.isHidden()?"+h":"";

    return prop;
}
```